# Admin form for custom User in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-orm

I'm writing my first project in django. I need to create few types of users with different fields. I've created Client class with 1-1 relation with User and trying to create admin form for it

models.py

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete="CASCADE")
    new_field = models.CharField("New field", max_length=30)
```

And I'm trying to create form in django admin to manage Client instances with inlided User fields.

admin.py

```py
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User


class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'


class ExtendedClientAdmin(ClientAdmin):
    inlines = ClientAdmin.inlines + [UserInline]


admin.site.register(Client, ExtendedClientAdmin)
```

But I got following error:

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001B23F18B0D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work\test\vevn\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\work\test\vevn\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\work\test\vevn\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 425, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'backoffice.admin.UserInline'>: (admin.E202) 'auth.User' has no ForeignKey to 'backoffice.Client'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

How should I create form for Client admin with inlined User fields?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have first to do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

In order to map your changes to the db